# Retrieving complete information for the memberof (AD) attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to retrieve the complete information on the membership for an user. This was scripted in SSIS (Microsoft Visual Studio 10) with the script transformation editor component written in C#.

By the way, in the CONSOLE (cmd) if we retrieve with the `dsget user "cn=...." -memberof` I am able to retrieve all the groups of an user...

What I want is to get the membership  like:

> CN=Name1,OU=WZA,OU=WWWWW,DC=XXXX,DC=YYYY,DC=ZZZZ
>   CN=Name2,OU=WZA,OU=WWWWW,DC=XXXX,DC=YYYY,DC=ZZZY
>   CN=Name3,OU=WZA,OU=WWWWW,DC=XXXX,DC=YYYY,DC=ZZZA

what I am getting: (only the first line...)

> CN=Name1,OU=WZA,OU=WWWWW,DC=XXXX,DC=YYYY,DC=ZZZZ

The code follows. How to change it to receive the complete information that AD holds in the *memberOf* attribute?
(in SSIS the attribute has a data type of unicode string with 3999 characters set as maximum, so truncation is hard to happen)

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string directory = Variables.LDAPConnection;
        string filter = Variables.LDAPFilter;
        string[] desiredAttributes = { "memberOf", 
                                         "displayname" 
                                         };

        using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(directory))
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, filter, desiredAttributes))
        {
            searcher.PageSize = 100;
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;


            using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    Output0Buffer.AddRow();

                    if (result.Properties["memberOf"] != null && result.Properties["memberOf"].Count > 0)
                    {
                        Output0Buffer.memberOf= result.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString();
                    }

                    if (result.Properties["displayname"] != null && result.Properties["displayname"].Count > 0)
                    {
                        Output0Buffer.displayname = result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
                    }                    

                }
            }
        }

        Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();
    }   

}
```

ps I do not know enough C#...

Comment: filter variable VALUE: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))`  NOT SURE about your request of the "code for variable class"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using the first record in the `memberOf` attribute:

```
Output0Buffer.memberOf= result.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString();
```

`result.Properties["memberOf"]` is an array. So you have to loop through that array and get each value.

Comment: but how I could do it in C#?

SOMETHING like:

`foreach (SearchResult result in results)
if (result.Properties["memberOf"] != null && result.Properties["memberOf"].Count > 0)
                    {
                        Output0Buffer.memberOf= result.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString();
                    }`

Comment: No. Do another `foreach` on `result.Properties["memberOf"]`.